# Cannot load static resource in a Lightning Container, with Namespace

Tags: namespaces, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, static-resource

My org has a namespace and I'm trying to load a static resource within a lightning:container in my lightning component. My lightning component and static resource, both have the same namespace. The browser complains that the server URL that Salesforce resolves the static resource to, is inaccessible. Has anyone done this before, successfully?

Here's how my lightning container has been defined:

```
<lightning:container src="{!$Resource.ns__resourcename + '/index.html'}" onmessage="{!c.doSomething}" aura:id="myapp" />
```